# Unable to use npm install with nodejs showing error

Tags: node.js

This is the error i am getting when i am trying to install npm package.
I have installed NODEJS and try to run my app.

```
C:\>npm install
npm ERR! install Couldn't read dependencies  
npm ERR! package.json ENOENT, open 'C:\package.json'
npm ERR! package.json This is most likely not a problem with npm itself.
npm ERR! package.json npm can't find a package.json file in your current directo
  ry.

npm ERR! System Windows_NT 6.2.9200
npm ERR! command "C:\\Program Files (x86)\\nodejs\\\\node.exe" "C:\\Program File
                  s (x86)\\nodejs\\node_modules\\npm\\bin\\npm-cli.js" "install"
npm ERR! cwd C:\
npm ERR! node -v v0.10.29
npm ERR! npm -v 1.4.14
npm ERR! path C:\package.json
npm ERR! code ENOPACKAGEJSON
npm ERR! errno 34
npm ERR!
npm ERR! Additional logging details can be found in:
npm ERR!     C:\npm-debug.log
npm ERR! not ok code 0
```

Comment: First of all you need to do npm in a valid folder....

Comment: I did that but still i am getting error